# How to prevent parent window from going into background after child is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, window

So, I've been running into a problem with many of my WPF applications where after closing children windows of a window, that window (usually my main window) will go into background, behind anything else I have open.  After some research, I found this bug report submitted to Microsoft: [**Bug Report**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586190/wpf-in-some-situations-after-child-window-closing-parent-window-goes-on-a-background) and their usual response of "The WPF team has recently reviewed this issue and will not be addressing it..."

Has anyone been successful at tackling this on their own?  It drives me mad and I can't figure out a solution.

**EDIT:**

I gave some thought to what James had recommended in his answer and after almost dismissing his suggestion due to the inconvenient nature of the window being on top of everything else, I came up with this:

```
ChildWindow.Closed += delegate
{
    ChildWindow = null;
    this.Topmost = true;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    this.Topmost = false;
};
```

So, when child's `Closed()` event is raised, I make sure that the parent window is the topmost.  Then, I let the thread sleep for 1 second and set topmost to false to allow other windows to overlay this parent window.

**Reason for the pause:** If I don't use a pause and just `this.Topmost = true` followed by `this.Topmost = false`, then the effect never takes place and the bug still occurs because of the timing for the bug.

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it works.  Microsoft needs to invest more resources into WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the Main window to:

```
Topmost=true
```

This should help a little, but will not solve the issue entirely.  Just keep in mind that if another application has the setting, they could end up on top of the application anyways.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: While it solves the issue of the application going into background, it introduces a problem of where the user won't be able to bring any other windows on top of the application.  i.e. If they want to bring their internet browser window forward on top of the application window.

Comment: Check out my edit, I took your idea and expanded on it.

Comment: That is exactly how I would handle this situation.  I also agree that a timer shouldn't need to be used, but the reality is that for some coding, topmost would be ideal without a sleep timer.  I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direct.  Thank you for the edit and the information on how to allow other windows to be at the top.

Comment: A pause has to be used; otherwise, there's not enough time for the bug to actuate and then `Topmost` to matter.  I've tested.

Comment: While your answer does not solve the issue completely, it lead me to my solution and it doesn't appear that there is anything better out there; thus, you get the credit. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just have left a comment under the question, but I don't have enough reputation.
I encountered this very same issue, and after playing a little bit with the solution presented here, realized that a cleaner solution would be to call Focus() on the parent instead of making it topmost, set a timer, then remove topmost:

```
ChildWindow.Closed += delegate
{
    ChildWindow = null;
    parentWindow?.Focus();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug is indeed really annoying since it does not occur all the time and can sometimes be hard to reproduce. I know the OP asked about WPF but here is my workaround for WinForms so far (I prefered to avoid the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` so that the UI remains responsive):

```
ChildWindow.Closed += delegate { this.Activate(); };
```